# Not able to debug webservice using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, web-services

i have tried the webservice example mentioned in the  below link. 
https://codezone4.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/restful-web-services-java-mysql-and-json/.

i build the application with maven deployed in tomcat then clicked on the webservice link in the chrome , not able to access my code.

Now i tried to debug with postman .

I clicked on my webservice class -> then debug -> debug configiuration
then i selected remote application 
there values of host and port are
Host : localhost
Port : 8080
then it is showing establishing connection for long time and after that it is showing Failed to connect to remote vm .connection timedout

Can you please guide me how to make deugger working in eclipse to debug the rest api call.

Comment: Is your application of type "Dynamic Web Module" ?

Comment: Also please check if your application is able to MySQL or not. Chances are your application is unable to connect to your MySQL. Please also verify with your tomcat logs if application is indeed up and running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can find quick solution (In Windows Environment with local host):

1) Download tomcat in your favorite drive (E.g. d: drive)

2) Open startup.bat file under tomcat/bin folder in notepad

3) Replace following line (Which appear at the end of file)

call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

with

call "%EXECUTABLE%" jpda start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

4) Restart your tomcat as it will start with listening port 8000

5) Open Eclipse->"Run"->"Debug configuration"-> Create "Remote Java Application" and provide following information:

```
 Name: sample-name

 Project: your project folder
```

6) Click on Debug button

Note: Make sure Connection properties will have 
Host: localhost
Port: 8000

7) Put debug point in your code

8) Open Postman and Hit sample REST API call as you will see the debug point will appear in your code

That's It!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from your query,

> clicked on my webservice class -> then debug -> debug

The project you created requires the restApplication to be deployed on a **running server**.

Prior To Testing ->  check http://localhost:8080 is up or not, and then publish the war into the server.

choose **Debug As-> Debug on Server**

Comment: yes  http://localhost:8080 is up and then only published the war on server and then chose deubg with remote application